# List the time zones for a Country

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am looking for the code that displays list of countries/regions in ruby on rails when selecting a specific country/region, it displays the time zone of it. For example when i choose “United Kingdom" as country/region then it should displays “(GMT +00:00)London" as Time Zone. My application runs on Rails 3.2.11. I am displaying all the countries using **countries** gem and all the time zones using **ActiveSupport::TimeZone**. I want to know if Ruby on Rails provide this functionality by default or if there is any other possible way to achieve this.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Did you already write something and would like to know if it can be done directly? If so, what did you write?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [TimeZone](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html) class. You can get all timezones list by:

```
zones_hash = ActiveSupport::TimeZone::MAPPING
```

And you can get time zone of any country as the following:

```
country_zone = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new("Europe/Skopje")
country_zone.formatted_offset
```

The output: `+01:00` for the above example.

Comment: Thanks mohamed. This really works. But I would like to know if I pass an argument like ('US') or ('AE'), will it give me the timezone available for them. Is there any way for that?

Comment: @ShabiniRajadas you should use string from Mapping Hash. So, you can use as the following: `ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new("Pacific Time (US & Canada)")` Or `ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new("Mountain Time (US & Canada)")` .. Because You should specify the place.

Answer (score 7):

In Rails 5.2 this is simple: `ActiveSupport::TimeZone.country_zones("US")`